# Closing StreamReader after ReadToEnd

Tags: c#, .net, file-io

Is it possible somehow to close StreamReader after calling ReadToEnd method in construction like this:

```
string s = new StreamReader("filename", Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd();
```

Any alternative elegant construction with the same semantics will be also accepted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think the method you're really after is [File.ReadAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalltext.aspx), if you're just trying to read all the text from a file in the shortest possible code.

If you don't specify the encoding, it will use UTF-8 automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a *[using](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(VS.80).aspx)* statement, which *automatically* closes the stream:

```
string s = null;    
using ( StreamReader reader = new StreamReader( "filename", Encoding.UTF8 ) { s = reader.ReadToEnd(); }
```

Comment: I do it this way now, but hope what there is a shorter solution without explicit declaration of StreamReader variable.

Comment: @jon-skeet's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 2):

No there isn't but it's always a good practice to use dispose objects who inherit
form IDisposable. If you don't do this in a loop you will get memory leaks

```
string s = string.Empty;
using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filename", Encoding.UTF8))
{
  s = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: There's no need or point in calling Close as well as Dispose. Just putting it in a using statement is enough.

Comment: I agree but the all the developers must know that expensive objects must be closed & disposed if you're not using it anymore.

Comment: No, they need to be closed *or* disposed. Adding a call to Close like that just adds clutter. Furthermore, if it *were* required, you'd have to put it in a finally block anyway.

Comment: Ok you should not close explicitly, but I think you should always(if possible) use the using statement for objects who inherit from IDisposable. Or am I incorrect?

Comment: No, that's fine - the using statement is good, the call to Close is unnecessary fluff. I'll edit the answer for you. (I can't remember offhand how much rep you need to edit your own answers.)

Comment: (I'd also personally not set a value for s, given that it will be overwritten in every situation except where an exception is thrown.)