# Send large string from silverlight(OB) to asp.net without query string

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight

I am working in Silverlight(out of browser mode) project. I have sent data from silverlight end to server end by using WebBrowser(query string). But query sting has capacity problem. You know that query string max length is 2048(IE). But I need to send huge data from client to server. Now what should I do to send huge data(greater than 2048) from silverlight to asp.net host. I do not want to .ashx. I want to use .aspx. thanks

Comment: Post it. using forms POST method and WebClient possibly

Answer (score 0):

The example is here [Post data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718420/sending-post-data-with-c-sharp)

You will need these includes:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.Net;
```

Comment: Thanks.I have seen different ans. but not acceptable ans. in your link which answer should I follow?